# C# Console Output Formatting

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to get a factorial to be displayed as for example (factorial of 5 is 5*4*3*2*1)

I'm using a method for the factorial, but it doesn't accept the line `Console.Write(i + " x ");` in my code.

Any help would be great.
here is my code.

```
//this method asks the user to enter a number and returns the factorial of that number
static double Factorial()
{
    string number_str;
    double factorial = 1;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter number");
    number_str = Console.ReadLine();

    int num = Convert.ToInt32(number_str);

    // If statement is used so when the user inputs 0, INVALID is outputed
    if (num <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid option");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        number_str = Console.ReadLine();

        num = Convert.ToInt32(number_str);
        //Console.Clear();
        //topmenu();
        //number_str = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    if (num >= 0)
    {
        while (num != 0) 
        {
            for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                factorial = factorial * i;
            }
            Console.Write(i + " x ");

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("factorial of " + number_str.ToString() + " is " + factorial);
            factorial = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("(please any key to return to main menu)");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            topmenu();
        }
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `i` is an `integer`, you should set it as a `string`: `Console.Write(i.ToString() + " x ");`

Comment: `string.Join("*", Enumerable.Range(1, 5))` is `1*2*3*4*5`

Comment: @TimS. How is that going to *compute* the factorial?

Comment: @ReedCopsey it doesn't, it computes the string. Computing the factorial is another matter, and I don't see much benefit to doing both at the same time: any factorial that fits in a `double` can be computed in so few iterations (171! > double.MaxValue) that the double looping isn't a performance issue, and it complicates the code.

Comment: @TimS. True - in that case, to get the same results, you'd need to do `string.Join("*", Enumerable.Range(1,5).Reverse()))` ;)

Comment: This question is more about how important code style is than programming in C# itself.
Should it be here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your for loop isn't using braces, so the scope is just one line.

Try adding braces appropriately:

```
for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--)
{
    factorial = factorial * i;
    Console.Write(i.ToString() + " x ");
}

Console.WriteLine("factorial of " + number_str.ToString() + " is " + factorial);
```

Without the braces, the `i` variable only exists on the next statement (`factorial = factorial * i;`), and no longer exists in scope by the time you call `Console.Write`.

You will likely also want to remove the call to `Console.Clear` immediately following this `Write`, or you will not see it.

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `ToString` be implicit? `Console.Write(1 + "foo");` will compile without issue.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Yeah - being stupid - edited to fix (and show the "real" problem.

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution to consider

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter number");

    int input;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || input <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have enter an invald option");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter number");
    }

    Console.Write("Factorial of " + input + " is : ");

    int output = 1;
    for (int i = input; i > 0; i--)
    {
        Console.Write((i == input) ? i.ToString() : "*" + i);
        output *= i;
    }
    Console.Write(" = " +output);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

int.TryParse() will be beneficial for you, so the program doesn't crash if the user inputs a non-integer

also, you may want something besides an integer.  Factorials get very large very fast - anything over 16 will return a wrong result.